# how to get sum and count date with groupby in laravel?

Tags: laravel

I want to get sum of afghani budget and count of record group by of afghani columns from agreements table.

```
$af = DB::table('agreements')
         ->selectRaw('sum(afghani) as sum_af, count(*) as af')
         ->groupby('afghani')
         ->get();
```

my blade file

```
     @foreach ($af as $data)
             <tr>
             <td>3</td>
             <td>{{ $data->af }}</td>
             <td>{{ number_format($data->sum_af, 2)}}</td>
             <td>Af</td>
            </tr>
     @endforeach
```

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: Your query logic is weird. Can you explain what you wanted to get?

Comment: i want to get sum of afghani budget from agreements table and count records group by afghani columns from agreements table.

Comment: You tried to groupby by afhgani and to get sum of afghani. How is it possible.

Comment: You can not get sum of afghani and also group by afgani

Comment: This query prints the total budget in Afghani correctly and does not print the count of records correctly

Comment: You can count based of condition not based of a field. What exactly do you want to count?

Comment: count value just 1, right?

Comment: Try to use separate queries.

Comment: Can you provide some example data and an expected result?

Comment: I have three types of budgets
1- Dollar
2- Euro
3- Afghan
I want to count budgets based on these three types and also the total budget based on these three types.

Comment: I want to know how many records we have in the Afghani or dollar sector and also the total budget in Afghani or dollars.

Comment: @EzatullahTabish.better post sql with data of that table  and expected result in question so that some one can try with it.

Answer (score 0):

I supposed you have a model named "Aggrement" and a column named "budgets" or "sector" or anything that can be including "Afghan" and "Dollar" and "Euro".

It is better you use separate query and if you want to use eloquent query like this:

```
$afghani_sum = Aggrement::where('budgets', 'afghani')->sum('budgets');
$afghani_count = Aggrement::where('budgets', 'afghani')->count('budgets');
```

I hope this is the answer to your question.